# python: c-struct and wintypes

Tags: python, c, struct

I'm trying to implement a python interface. I have a problem with the definition of the c-structure. How to generate the inner struct (LinV) in the main-struct?

The definition from the manuel:

```
typedef struct
{
float MaxExcitation;

struct LinVal
    {
    double MeasValue;
    double RefValue;
    } LinV[SEN_LIN_DATA_MAX];
} Data;
```

python code:

```
class LinV(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('NeasValue', c_double),
                ('RefValue', c_double)]


class Data(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('MaxExcitation', c_float),
                ('LinV', ???????)]
```

Thx
Markus

Answer (score 0):

You just multiply to specify the array:

```
from ctypes import *

SEN_LIN_DATA_MAX = 3

class LinV(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('NeasValue', c_double),
                ('RefValue', c_double)]


class Data(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('MaxExcitation', c_float),
                ('LinV', LinV * SEN_LIN_DATA_MAX)]

d = Data(2.0,
   (LinV(1.2, 3.2),
    LinV(2.2, 2.2), 
    LinV(3.2, 1.2),
))
```